# How to solve sender mail and receiver same issues in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, sendmail

I want, when a user will submit the contact form then I'll get a mail from the user mail. Everything is okay here, but the issue is I get the mail from my own mail when a user submits the form. Mean, sender mail and receiver mail is the same. That's why I can't see from which mail the mail cam Where is the problem?. Help me to resolve the issues.

***views.py:***

```
def ContactME(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        MessageSenderName = request.POST.get('name')
        SenderMessage = request.POST.get('message')
        SenderEmail = request.POST.get('email')
        Contact.objects.create(
            Name = MessageSenderName,
            Email = SenderEmail,
            Message = SenderMessage,
        )

        send_mail(
            '(Portfolio)' + MessageSenderName,
            SenderMessage,
            SenderEmail,
            ['XXXX@gmail.com'],
        )

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

***settings.py:***

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = xxxxxxxxxx
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: You cannot send email from your user email address, you don't have his email password etc.

Comment: you can only send mail from your email that is set in settings, you cannot use user email address without their credentials

Comment: so now how can I contact with the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send emil from user email. Insted you can send all the submitted info to your mail from the same mail.

Comment: okay I got the piont